# GUI in python for input data

Tags: python, dataframe, file, user-interface, input

I want to code a GUI in python, which uses browser window for surfing in folders, and can select multiple files and save their directory address in a dataframe. it can surf multi times and each one can select multi files' addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I found [PyQt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/) to be pretty easy to use for making GUIs in python.

You can make a button:

```
file_button = QPushButton("Browse for files")
```

Then define a function to run when you click the button:

```
def file_button_on_click():
    files = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(...)
```

Then connect that function to your button:

```
file_button.clicked.connect(file_button_on_click)
```